# How to move the laravel 5.1 User model to \App\Models\User?

Tags: php, authentication, model, laravel-5.1

Is it possible to tell Laravel that I have moved the User.php model?

Laravel 5.1

```
FatalErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 126: 
Class '\App\User' not found
```

I really wasn't keen on having all the models at the root of the App folder in laravel 5.1 so I created a new folder and placed all the model php files within it: `\App\Models`

I altered the auth controller to use the new `use App\Models\User;` and corrected all the model files within the model folder..

However when i load the page I get the error mentioned above.

(the other model files of course work fine as it is my code accessing them, it is just the prebuilt auth stuff from laravel 5.1)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For example if you create a folder (eg app/Models), there are two ways to move your models:

**1) Laravel5 style = Use PSR4**

Namespace all your model files with namespace `App\Models;`
Access your models anywhere with their full namespace, eg: `\App\Models\User::find(1);`

**2) Laravel4 style**

Load your model with composer autoloader. In composer.json add:

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database",
            "app/Models"            
        ],
        ...
```

You don't need to namespace your Models. They are in ther root namespace
In namespaced files you can access them as \User::find(1);

**Extra notes:**

- If you change tha namespace of User model you have to update `config\auth.php`  =>  `'model'=> App\Models\User::class`
- The easiest way get rid of long namespaces is to import your models in the begining of your php files, For example: `use App\Models\User;`

**Links:**

- https://laracasts.com/lessons/where-do-i-put-this
- http://ryantablada.com/post/the-repository-pattern-in-action
- https://laracasts.com/lessons/repositories-simplified

Comment: If we do something like User::find(1); and define the namespace in the beginning (use App\User;). Is it still PSR4?

Comment: for optimum results i suggest you do all three (extra note included) especially if your half way through your build and wish to implement this change.

Answer (score 40):

You need to modify your `Project/config/auth.php` file
on `'model'=> AppName\Models\User::class,`

Comment: Don't forget to run composer dump-autoload after moving class

Comment: Can you explain what this is doing and why it needs changing? Thanks